# Properties of power series and their analytic continuation

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series

Suppose a power series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$$ is valid for $|z|<R$, and can be analytically continued to some function $f(z)$, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ , except for a finite number of points $z$. Suppose I can prove some functional properties of the power series. My question is do these properties also hold for the analytic continuation $f(z)$ ?

Comment: What sort of properties? Many properties hold for the continuation by the identity theorem.

Comment: @Daniel Properties such as $f(-z)=f(z)$ or functional equation type properties relating $f(z)$ and $f(1-z)$.

Comment: If the functional equation can be expressed analytically (which it should, considering that $f$ is analytic), then the identity theorem yields the permanence of the relation.

Comment: Other properties such as "is nonzero" are problematic of course.